# I am a beginner in python. Can someone help me to get a star pattern like this?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have tried these steps but I don't know what to do after trying them.

```
num = int(input("Enter an integer number greater than or equal to 1: "))

if num > 1:
  for x in range(0, num):
    for y in range(0, x+1):
        print("*", end = " ")
    print("")

for x in range(num,1,-1):
    for y in range(0,x-1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print("")
```

The pattern I would like to get is

```
*
**
***
**
*
**
*
*
```

Comment: if you're a beginner i strongly recommend starting with hello world, then math, then a simple calculator and then - you can go on with these stuff.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the pattern correctly. Did you mean the height of every next 'hill' is one less than the previous 'hill'?

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal yes

Answer (score 1):

Hope this does the job. The outer for loop is supposed to decrease the height of a hill by one at every iteration and the inner two for loops print the hill for every height.

```
num = int(input("Enter an integer number greater than or equal to 1: "))

for height in range (num, 0, -1):
    for i in range (1, height):
        print ('*'*i)
    for j in range (height, 0, -1):
        print ('*'*j)
```